# Google switches primary and secondary email accounts regardless of login order

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-chrome, google-multi-login

I have two separate email accounts logged into Google Chrome that switch order regardless of the order I log into them. I want to stop this from happening.

I log into my personal email first, so that the url is: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/`and my professional email second, so that the url is `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/`.

However, Google will automatically change my secondary email to be my primary email, so that when I type in `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/`, my secondary email now appears.

This is an issue because my professional email does not have a YouTube login. Thus I will not be able to use my YouTube account because my personal email is now by secondary email.

Again, logging out of both and logging into the preferred email first does not help. Google switches them with a few minutes anyways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is just an educated guess, but it might have something to do with the fact that one of the accounts is a paid one and probably for some reason Google gives precedence to that one.

Comment: You can try to clear cookies/or login using incognito mode in your browser. If nothing of this helps and order of logins still changes automatically, then it's way of how Google works.